# How to call a variable in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

I have a class set up like this. How do I call the variable `datasets` in public functions in the same class? `datasets.contains(...)` doesn't work.

```
export default class QueryController {
    private datasets: Datasets = null; 

    constructor(datasets: Datasets) {
        this.datasets = datasets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class members are accessed using `this`. You can also simply declare your constructor parameter as `private` to avoid having to manually map it to a property.

```
export default class QueryController {
    constructor(private datasets: Datasets) {
    }

    doSomething() {
        return this.datasets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `this.datasets` as this is class property.